# Multiple multiclass classification

Tags: neural-networks, multi-class, keras

Let's say we need to recognize 5-digit zip code from an image, and we want to do that without any sliding window.

If we use 5 `Keras` models to recognize each digit of zip code, we would have something like this as output layer of every model:

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', init='unifotm'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

What if we want to predict classes of all digit at once?

It seems logical to have `5x10` output, where we apply `softmax` to every row separately. Is there anything like this in `Keras`? Or maybe we can merge those 5 models into one somehow and train all of them simultaneously?

And if it would require a custom layer for such representation, how error function should behave?

The first idea is to set `error = number of misclassified digits`, but would it be sufficient enough? How would model understand what digit it got wrong and what weights should be adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it was quite a trivial question and the solution is to use few outputs with code like this:

```
image_input = Input(shape=(h, w, c), name='image')

x = Convolution2D()(image_input)

# some layers here

heads = []
for i in range(number_of_outputs):
    layer_name = 'head{}'.format(i)
    head = Dense(50, init = 'glorot_normal')(x)
    head = LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.1)(head)
    head = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', init='uniform', name = layer_name)(head)
    heads.append(head)

loss = {'head{}'.format(i):'categorical_crossentropy' for i in range(number_of_outputs)}

model = Model(input = [image_input], output = heads)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss)
```